# UNDEFINED when trying to get value of an attribute

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the value of the attribute 'data-tablename'.

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: 'post', 
  url: "<?= base_url(); ?>table/moveTable/",
  data: "table_name=" + $(this).attr("data-tablename"), 
  success: function(r) {
      $.notify($(this).attr("data-tablename") + " was successfully added", "success");
  }
});
```

When I try this code, I get the message "undefined was successfully added"

How can I get the value of it?

Comment: Well, `this` in that context is the ajax function, and why would the ajax function have a data attribute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `var tableName = $(this).attr("data-tablename");` before ajax invocation and then replace `$(this).attr("data-tablename")` with tableName variable

Answer (score 1):

You should assign $(this) to a variable before the ajax action, and then use that variable in the anonymous functions:

```
var $this = $(this);

$.ajax({ 
  type: 'post', 
  url: "<?= base_url(); ?>table/moveTable/",
  data: { "table_name": $(this).attr("data-tablename") },
  success: function(r) {
      $.notify($this.attr("data-tablename") + " was successfully added", "success");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a function defined in another function, `this` in the inner function will not be the same as the outer function unless there is something to specifically set it to be so. In this case you can use jQuery.ajax's `context` configuration, this sets the value of `this` in all the callbacks to whatever you want.

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: 'post', 
  url: "<?= base_url(); ?>table/moveTable/",
  data: "table_name=" + $(this).attr("data-tablename"), 
  context: this,
  success: function(r) {
      $.notify($(this).attr("data-tablename") + " was successfully added", "success");
  }
});
```